# Not yet here or Not here yet?

Tags: phrases

I would like to know which one is correct, "She is not yet here." or "She is not here yet."
Or are they both correct?

Comment: Related question, [Position of “yet” in a causative sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170903/position-of-yet-in-a-causative-sentence). Using "she is not here yet" is more idiomatic than the other. Both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

'Yet' is most often used as an adverb (as an indexical temporal noun).  As such, it could go anywhere in the sentence (except inside a noun phrase).  However, 'yet' can also be a conjunction (meaning 'but'), so it shouldn't be used as an adverb at the beginning of a clause.  When used within a noun phrase, 'yet' is an adjective meaning 'still' ('enduring').